Handling Documentation Overlap in Product Feature Queries
I have two products, X and Y, each with its own set of documentation detailing their features and functionalities. I've processed these documents by dividing them into segments based on word count and stored these segments in vector database for both products.
However, there's a challenge I'm facing:

There is a high likelihood of overlap between the documents. When discussing the products in an article, I don’t mention the product name in every paragraph, but it is implied that the features described are directly linked to the respective product.
I also have other documentation that largely overlaps with the previous product documentation but contains subtle differences.

The problem arises when I ask a question about a feature in product X that doesn’t exist in X but is available in Y. The system mistakenly selects the documentation that includes the feature (from product Y), assuming it exists in X, and provides an incorrect answer.
How can I handle this issue to ensure that the system correctly identifies whether a feature exists in the queried product and avoids providing incorrect answers based on overlapping documentation?
Any advice or approach would be greatly appreciated!. If this is not right forum to ask such questions, apologies.
